# Auto scale a div with background to fit into its parent using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I am making a application layout that consists of left and right section.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.leftSection {
  flex: 0.7;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.rightSection {
  flex: 0.2;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftSection">
    Left Section
  </div>
  <div class="rightSection">
    Right Section
  </div>
</div>
```

In this the `.rightSection` div will be as it is, and need to look only into left section.

The left section will have a background image with some space in which I need to include the sub component diagram's.

The background image will be like,

[image]

And the expected result of filling the sub components is like,

[image]

So I have tried to fill the left section like,

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.leftSection {
  flex: 0.7;
}

.rightSection {
  flex: 0.2;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.bgContainer {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png');
    height: 401px;
    width: 688px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.coil {
    position: absolute;
    top: 49.55%;
    left: 24.3%;   
}
.evaporator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7.25%;
    left: 54.5%;
}
.compressor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53.15%;
    left: 59.2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftSection">
    <div class="bgContainer">
        <div class="coil">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="evaporator">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="compressor">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightSection">
    Right Section
  </div>
</div>
```

So far everything is fine. But I am implementing this in for tablet screen's where the width of the device will start from `600px` to `1400px` .

So i need to make this section responsive across all the devices starting from width `600px` to `1400px`.

So I breakdown setting up some width to the parent div considering it as device width like `600`, `1024`, and `1200`(just for eg..,) I have made it like this static width.

```css
.first {
  width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 30px;
}

.second {
  width: 1024px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 30px;
}

.third {
  width: 1200px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 30px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.leftSection {
  flex: 0.7;
}

.rightSection {
  flex: 0.2;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.bgContainer {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png');
    height: 401px;
    width: 688px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.coil {
    position: absolute;
    top: 49.55%;
    left: 24.3%;   
}
.evaporator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7.25%;
    left: 54.5%;
}
.compressor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53.15%;
    left: 59.2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftSection">
    <div class="bgContainer">
        <div class="coil">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="evaporator">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="compressor">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightSection">
    Right Section
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="second">
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftSection">
    <div class="bgContainer">
        <div class="coil">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="evaporator">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="compressor">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightSection">
    Right Section
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="third">
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftSection">
    <div class="bgContainer">
        <div class="coil">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="evaporator">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="compressor">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightSection">
    Right Section
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In this above snippet, inside `.first`, the left section comes out and in `.second` and `third` also its in different position.

So finally my requirement is how to make the left section with background image to be responsive along with all tablet screens starting from `600` pixels to `1400` pixels at least.

**In real application:** Right now my main issue is that the design goes out of the screen's mostly at bottom like,

[image]

I have tried using `transform: scale(2.0);` but still the left section goes beyond the screen. as like the above image, should I need to calculate this scale value dynamically? Kindly please help me to get out this problem as I am struggling for very long time.

**Update1:**

If I give width to specific div like,

```
.coil {
  position: absolute;
  top: 49.55%;
  left: 24.3%;
  width: 17%;
}

.evaporator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.25%;
  left: 54.5%;
  width: 12%;
}

.compressor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 53.15%;
  left: 59.2%;
  width: 13%;
}
```

then I get issues when the device height is smaller or larger.

After the implementation,

The below screenshot is captured in the screen viewport with *height: 844* and *width: 1280*

[image]

The below screenshot is captured in the screen viewport with *height: 552* and *width: 1024*

[image]

Comment: have a look at giving the parents `position: relative` in order for `width` and `height` with `100%` to work or look at flexbox

Comment: @Alex, Giving `position: relative` to parent also lead to distort of UI of absolute elements.

Comment: Is `background-size: contain` what you're looking for in the .container selector?

Comment: Update the withs like this.
//  width: 1024px;
width:100%;
aspect-ratio:1024/600;

Comment: Why don't you turn your image and components into SVG, an draw them with tools like D3 and make the graph responsive. It will be tedious, but the end result would be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this CSS code for the .container class using background-size: cover:

```
.container {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we could just make the background image as normal block so that it will be the main width and height. Then we can set the width of the image to `100%` and With background image being like that, it will maintain its aspect ratio. Since you manually calculate the `top`, `left` positions for the components, why not manually calculate the `width` as well:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.leftSection {
  flex: 0.7;
}

.rightSection {
  flex: 0.2;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.bgContainer {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.coil {
  position: absolute;
  top: 49.55%;
  left: 24.3%;
  width: 17.4418605%;
}

.evaporator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.25%;
  left: 54.5%;
  width: 11.627907%;
}

.compressor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 53.15%;
  left: 59.2%;
  width: 13.0813953%;
}

.component img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftSection">
    <div class="bgContainer">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png" class="bg-img" />
      <div class="component coil">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
      </div>
      <div class="component evaporator">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
      </div>
      <div class="component compressor">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightSection">
    Right Section
  </div>
</div>
```

This should be responsive for all devices. You could also automate the calculating with javascript if you really need to, but I made this solution fixed because you manually calculate the `top`, `left` positions.

Comment: This is giving issue in different viewport. Please look at the update given in the question.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan did you move the background image to `<img>` tag as I suggested though? I can't reproduce your update in my code above, it seems to me that your updated code has no background image as the anchor

Comment: Yes I have moved the background to `<img>` tag but in real tab it is not positioned properly like above updated UI.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan hmm that's odd, it's probably something to do with the tab, or there's some CSS that causes the images to behave that way (the evaporator is cropped on the right side), because at least in my snippet, it doesn't have problem. IMO you should try to make the snippet here that could reproduce the problem in here

Answer (score 1):

With *in document SVG*, you can use the SVG as any other regular image and size it to your requirements, while still being able to access the HTML making up the SVG and modify its CSS properties.

**tl;dr**

- create a `display: none` *in doc SVG*
- put the external images in a `symbol` element with an `id` in the `defs` section.
- use the the symbol in your regular HTML with `<svg><use href="#the_id"></use></svg>`

**read**

Because the entire SVG is treated as a single image, all elements in that SVG will stay in their respective locations and scale proportionally without requiring any CSS to position or resize them.

This is what I did for the snippet:

- Created a SVG with given images at at orginal size (688x401px) with [SVGEdit V7](https://svgedit.netlify.app/editor/index.html).
- Added the SVG to the HTML as an in document SVG, enabled it to stretch with given ratio 688:401.
- Used a main Flexbox container holding the SVG and a text panel.
- Defined a few size constraints forcing Flexbox to wrap for responsiveness. You can easily modify the `flex` and `min-width` in elements `.spec` and `.info` to meet your requirements.
- Embedded the *heating component* images in `<a>` to show that you can use regular HTML tags in a SVG.
- Kept the CSS and HTML purposely to a bare minimum.

*(The demo uses a 3:2 ratio for the panels (the `flex` values) and `min-width: 20rem` (360px minus left/right spacing) to force the wrap).*

**snippet**

```css
*   { outline: 1px dashed } /* for debugging */

/* Globals */
*    { box-sizing: border-box }
body { margin: 0; width: 100%; min-height: 100vh }
a    { color: inherit }

/* DEMO */
.container { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap }
svg        { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100% }

/* Toy with 'flex' and 'min-width' values */
.spec { flex: 3; min-width: min(20rem, 100%); aspect-ratio: 688 / 401 }
.info { flex: 2; min-width: min( 8rem, 100%); align-self: stretch }

.info { padding: 1rem }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="spec"><svg><use href="#svg-heating"></use></svg></div>
    <div class="info">
        <h3>Panel</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aeterno facilisi accusamus no pri. Per aeque pertinacia eu. Ut eum enim oporteat, eruditi abhorreant ex est, ferri eirmod appellantur ius ex. Per volutpat argumentum eu. Deterruisset consequuntur nam ex, pro ea elit mazim, an graeco facilisi mea.
        <p>Ad quodsi deleniti placerat vel, vis minim dolores no. Volumus partiendo id ius, sit ne habeo utamur inimicus. Vulputate mnesarchum sit no, essent possim ocurreret te has, et pro modo urbanitas. His facilisis honestatis ex.
    </div>
</div>


<!-- hidden, in document SVG -->
<svg style="display: none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Created with SVG-edit - https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit-->
    <defs>
        <symbol id="svg-heating" viewBox="0 0 688 401">
            <image id="svg_bg" height="401" width="688" x="0" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png" y="0" />
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><image id="svg_coil" height="90"  width="120" x="168" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" y="199"/></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><image id="svg_evap" height="70"  width="80"  x="375" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" y="29" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><image id="svg_comp" height="120" width="90"  x="408" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" y="213"/></a>
        </symbol>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftSection">
    <div class="subContainer">
      <!-- Your subcomponents here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightSection">
    Right Section
  </div>
</div>





    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .leftSection {
      flex: 0.7;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }

    .rightSection {
      flex: 0.2;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    <div class="container">
      <div class="leftSection">
        Left Section
      </div>
      <div class="rightSection">
        Right Section
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).